# Issues adding CoreData in new update of app

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, ios7, ios6

i have question regarding my app update, i have an app that is avaialble in the iTunesStore and that version does not include coredata in the app. But now i have added CoreData in the new version of the app and submitted to apple store, my question is that will the app will work fine or it will crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why should it crash? If you simply erase all the saved data and then convert it to CoreData database - you most certainly won't face any crash.

There is a thing to note here - this might not be the best way to solve the problem. Also read about `CoreData Versioning` mechanisms as they will save you from fails in updates later on.

You can also hypothetically test the behavior of your app like this - download it from the AppStore, launch it  and do things, then use Xcode to install the new version on top of it and see what happens.

Comment: Just a note that "use Xcode to install the new version" isn't really a good test because of the differences in how Xcode installs vs. how iTunes (or a direct install) works.  Xcode merely copies application resources over the existing installation (without removing anything) where iTunes replaces the entire application bundle (but not the Documents directory)  Shouldn't be an issue here, but it can cause problems in cases where resources are changing.

Comment: @David sure, I know that. An alternative route would be to upload 2 separate builds on TestFlight and to see what happens - that's how we actually tested everything so far.

Answer (score 2):

It'll crash if you write crashing code. Using Core Data or not using it is completely irrelevant to the question of whether the app will crash.